# Getting ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: http, intellij-idea, soap, karate

```
I am trying to run a demo scenario for Soap XML request . Have used the sample calculator web service . I works fine when i trigger the request from Soap UI .But the connection fails on trying to access the request from IntelliJ using Karate .
```

```
@SoapTest
    Feature:   
    Background:
    * url 'http://www.dneonline.com'
    * path 'calculator.asmx'
      * configure ssl = true

    Scenario: soap 1.1
        Given url apiURL
    And request
        """
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap:Body>
            <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
              <intA>2</intA>
              <intB>3</intB>
            </Add>
          </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        """
        When soap action 'http://tempuri.org/Add'
        Then status 200
        And match /Envelope/Body/AddResponse/AddResult == 5
        And Print response
```

**Below is the karate Config file being used **

```
 function() {   
          var config = {
            apiURL: 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'
          };

          karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
          karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
          karate.configure('ssl', { trustAll: true });
          return config;
        }
```

Error Details:
  12:38:56.822 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to www.dneonline.com:80 [www.dneonline.com/45.40.165.23] failed: connect timed out, http call failed after 5068 milliseconds for URL: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx/calculator.asmx
        12:38:56.822 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
        org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to www.dneonline.com:80 [www.dneonline.com/45.40.165.23] failed: connect timed out

```
I am not quite sure if i need to configure any proxy setting in Intellij or in the karate framework. 
or if it is something to do with the firewall as i am using my company's system.

Thanks .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes maybe you have to set a proxy: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

```
* configure proxy = 'http://my.proxy.host:8080'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt reply Peter... The solution given by you works fine . Many Thanks :)

Comment: do not add answer when you want to just comment.